# How to share Context data between MassTransit Consumers while using the `IBusControl` for publishing messages?

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I am using MassTransit 7.2.2 in a .NET Core application with RabbitMQ(for local development) and SQS(for deployment) where a single message processing can result in multiple new messages getting created and processed.

All the messages share the same base type

```
public class BaseMessage : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public BaseMessage()
    {
        CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; init; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; }
    public Guid? ConversationId { get; set; }
}
```

The basic flow of processing is same for all messages, there is a Service per Consumer.

```
public class FirstMessage : BaseMessage
{

}

public class FirstConsumer : IConsumer<FirstMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<FirstConsumer> _logger;
    private readonly FirstService _service;

    public FirstConsumer(ILogger<FirstConsumer> logger, FirstService service)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _service = service;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<FirstMessage> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"FirstConsumer CorrelationId: {context.CorrelationId} and ConversationId: {context.ConversationId} and InitiatorId: {context.InitiatorId}");
        _service.Process(context.Message);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class FirstService
{
    private readonly IBusControl _busControl;
    private readonly ILogger<FirstService> _logger;

    public FirstService(IBusControl busControl, ILogger<FirstService> logger)
    {
        _busControl = busControl;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Process(FirstMessage firstMessage)
    {
        var secondMessage = new SecondMessage();
        _busControl.Publish(secondMessage);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The above code is an example and the actual code base has 30+ consumers and all have the same pattern, i.e there is a Service per Consumer and the message is passed to the Service for processing.

I am trying to implement a solution for tracing messages end to end by using the Ids.

1. ConversationId - Unique Id for tracing logs of all Consumers in a graph
2. CorrelationId  - Unique Id for tracing logs within a Consumer
3. InitiatorId    - Parent Id

There is a message processing graph that looks like

> FirstConsumer -> SecondConsumer -> ThirdConsumer.

I have the following Filters

> ConsumeFilter

```
public class SimpleConsumeMessageFilter<TContext, TMessage> : IFilter<TContext>
    where TContext : class, ConsumeContext<TMessage>
    where TMessage : class
{
    public SimpleConsumeMessageFilter()
    {

    }

    public async Task Send(TContext context, IPipe<TContext> next)
    {
        LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", context.CorrelationId);
        LogContext.PushProperty("ConversationId", context.ConversationId);
        LogContext.PushProperty("InitiatorId", context.InitiatorId);
        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateScope("consume-filter");
    }
}

public class SimpleConsumeMessagePipeSpec<TConsumer, TMessage> : IPipeSpecification<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>>
    where TConsumer : class
    where TMessage : class
{
    public void Apply(IPipeBuilder<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>> builder)
    {
        builder.AddFilter(new SimpleConsumeMessageFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>, TMessage>());
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationResult>();
    }
}

public class SimpleConsumePipeSpecObserver : IConsumerConfigurationObserver
{
    public void ConsumerConfigured<TConsumer>(IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer> configurator)
        where TConsumer : class
    {
        
    }

    public void ConsumerMessageConfigured<TConsumer, TMessage>(IConsumerMessageConfigurator<TConsumer, TMessage> configurator)
        where TConsumer : class
        where TMessage : class
    {
        configurator.AddPipeSpecification(new SimpleConsumeMessagePipeSpec<TConsumer, TMessage>());
    }
}
```

> PublishFilter

```
public class SimplePublishMessageFilter<TMessage> : IFilter<PublishContext<TMessage>> where TMessage : class
{
    public SimplePublishMessageFilter()
    {

    }

    public async Task Send(PublishContext<TMessage> context, IPipe<PublishContext<TMessage>> next)
    {

        if (context.Headers.TryGetHeader("ConversationId", out object @value))
        {
            var conversationId = Guid.Parse(@value.ToString());
            context.ConversationId = conversationId;
        }
        else
        {
            if (context.Message is BaseMessage baseEvent && !context.ConversationId.HasValue)
            {
                context.ConversationId = baseEvent.ConversationId ?? Guid.NewGuid();
                context.Headers.Set("ConversationId", context.ConversationId.ToString());
            }
        }
        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateScope("publish-filter");
    }
}

public class SimplePublishMessagePipeSpec<TMessage> : IPipeSpecification<PublishContext<TMessage>> where TMessage : class
{
    public void Apply(IPipeBuilder<PublishContext<TMessage>> builder)
    {
        builder.AddFilter(new SimplePublishMessageFilter<TMessage>());
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationResult>();
    }
}

public class SimplePublishPipeSpecObserver : IPublishPipeSpecificationObserver
{
    public void MessageSpecificationCreated<TMessage>(IMessagePublishPipeSpecification<TMessage> specification)
        where TMessage : class
    {
        specification.AddPipeSpecification(new SimplePublishMessagePipeSpec<TMessage>());
    }
}
```

> Added to config via

```
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ConnectConsumerConfigurationObserver(new SimpleConsumePipeSpecObserver());
                cfg.ConfigurePublish(ppc =>
                {
                    ppc.ConnectPublishPipeSpecificationObserver(new SimplePublishPipeSpecObserver());
                });
                cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                cfg.Host("localhost", rmq =>
                {
                    rmq.Username("guest");
                    rmq.Password("guest");
                });
            });
```

With the above approach the 'CorrelationId' header is lost when the `SecondConsumer`'s filters are run.

I have tried the following change and it seems to flow the Ids across the Consumers.
However, taking this approach will impact large sections of code / tests that rely on the `IBusControl` interface. I am keeping this as a backup option in case I can't find any other solution.

```
public class FirstService
{
    private readonly ILogger<FirstService> _logger;

    public FirstService(ILogger<FirstService> logger)
    {            
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Process( ConsumeContext<FirstMessage> consumeContext)
    {
        var secondMessage = new SecondMessage();
        consumeContext.Publish(secondMessage);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to share the Context data between Consumers while using `IBusControl` for sending / publishing messages ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [explained in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish), consumers (and their dependencies) must use one of the following when sending/publishing messages:

- `ConsumeContext`, typically within the consumer itself
- `IPublishEndpoint` or `ISendEndpointProvider`, typically used by **scoped** dependencies of the consumer
- `IBus`, last resort, as all contextual data is lost from the inbound message

As for your final question, "Is there a way to share the Context data between Consumers while using IBusControl for sending / publishing messages?" the answer is no. The consume context would be needed to access any of the contextual data.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Patterson